# How to save foreign from html form (select)?

Tags: django, python-3.x, database, forms, django-queryset

*I can not save the appropriate value for ForeignKey from the form. The value of ForeignKey is always written to the database, with id = 1.*
*in html form the values from my model, which is in the database, are output to the select. But when sending data from the form, the values of the fields for which the type of foregonekey are written to the database all the time by id = 1*

**models.py:**

```
class Sportsman(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True, default=None, verbose_name='Имя')
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True, default=None, verbose_name='Фамилия')
gender = models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default=True, verbose_name='Пол')
tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, null=True, blank=True, default=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Турнир')

def __str__(self):
    return "Спортсмен(ка): %s %s, почта: %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Спортсмен'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Спортсмены'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Sportsman, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class SportsmenForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Sportsman
    exclude = ['created', 'updated']
```

**views.py:**

```
def sportsman(request):
documents = Document.objects.filter(is_active=True)

form = SportsmenForm(request.POST or None)

if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
    print(request.POST)
    print(form.cleaned_data)
    print(form.cleaned_data['email'])
    form.save()
    new_form = form.save()

return render(request, 'sportsman/sportsman.html', locals())

<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['BzBeiKE82LDcd3tmdzZGSmpOWQatc52SSO7ScEOm7eCVdXsHQWxerSzTZa6KC5xq'], 'first_name': ['test_name'], 'last_name': ['test_name'], '<select name=': ['3']}
```

>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, works fine for me.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = SportsmenForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
```

For using the form in the template, you don´t need to declare the inputs, Django does that for you. You just have to use the form as in the following example. Just adding the form fields as a variable will get you the right foreign key options.

```
<form action="{% url 'your_destination_view' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.first_name }}
    {{ form.last_name }}
    {{ form.gender }}
    {{ form.tournament }}

    <div><input type="submit" value="OK" name="form"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I changed the contents of my **views.py** and select came from my html form (selection of the values of my foreignkey). Now there is an empty field. But I think that on the right track. Do I need to somehow bring the foreign into my html select?
`<div class="form-select">
       <label for="tournament">Турнир</label>
       <select name="{{ form.tournament }}"></select>
</div>`

Comment: I will extend my answer in a minute, but you don´t need to declare the select input in the template, Django forms do that for you.

Comment: It worked! I don’t understand why nothing worked with the catomized form. But it doesn’t matter now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perfect. Please mark the answer as correct so people know there´s a solution. Best!

Answer (score 0):

When we use **default=True** and didn't send any value from form then django save first table value i.e. 1 So remove **blank=True and default=True** to save null in database.